# I need Android program for learning foreign word with ability for adding these words and translations

Tags: android, translation

I need Android app for learning foreign word with ability for adding these words with translations. It will be perfect, if I can manually add some count of words with translations from file, or other format (which e.g. GoldenDict supports), or from dropbox. Also I need ability to delete words from such app.

P.S.: I already have ["Learn English 6000 Words" (FunEasyLearn)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.funeasylearn.english) app. I want some other kind of app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [LearnWordsSymply](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.vt_tech.learnwordssimply).

The best way of learning language is to read something, write down the words, and learn the words, connected with context.

Don't try to learn 6000 words at once! Try rather small portions of 12-25 words.

[LearnWordsSymply](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.vt_tech.learnwordssimply) is very useful for such small portions of words.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest [AnkiDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ichi2.anki).

You can add new words:

- By manually by typing them
- By sending them from a dictionary app like GoldenDict and others
- By importing an APKG file (APKG files can be created from CSV/Excel files via [Anki Desktop](http://ankisrs.net/))
- By downloading shared decks (word lists that have been contributed by the community

You can also delete words you don't want, or suspend them, or tag them.

- Free, open source
- Half a million users, contributing a great variety of shared decks
- *Disclaimer: maintained by me*

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to learn words in English, I recommend the My Word List app

You can import your own words and notes contained in a spreadsheet. In the notes field you put your translations.

Links:

My Word List - Make Word Lists - Offline Dictionary app for Android.

Free Version: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fortylove.mywordlist.free

Disclaimer: I am the developer.